# Proper Python configuration after installing OpenCV from source

Tags: python, opencv, pip, pyenv

**Platform**: Raspberry Pi v4 B 8GB

**OS**: Raspberry Pi bullseye

**Architecture**: aarch64

I built and installed OpenCV in accordance with the [official openCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html). The process seems to have worked correctly:

```
deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ pkg-config --modversion opencv4
4.7.0

deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/
config-3.9.py  config.py  gapi  __init__.py  load_config_py2.py  load_config_py3.py  mat_wrapper  misc  python-3.9  utils
```

However, the module cannot be found when I use Python:

```
deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘cv2'
```

$PYTHONPATH wasn’t set, so I got a little further by setting it:

```
deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages

deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
OpenCV bindings requires "numpy" package.
Install it via command:
    pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

It appears that numpy isn’t installed. I’m using pyenv, so here’s the first question:

**1) What’s the proper procedure for using pip w/ pyenv?**

My system is using v3.92, but the project I’ll be working on uses 3.9.10:

```
deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ pyenv versions
* system (set by /home/deiter/.pyenv/version)
  3.9.10
deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ python --version
Python 3.9.2
```

I simply made 3.9.10 global and ran pip install. Is that the correct way to update v3.9.10 w/o affecting v3.9.2?

```
deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ pyenv global 3.9.10
deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ python --version
Python 3.9.10
deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install numpy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.19.5)
```

As shown, numpy  is already installed, so that’s the next question:

**2) If pip knows knows numpy is installed, why couldn’t Python find it?**

I was finally able to have success by updating $PYTHONPATH:

```
deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

deiter@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
4.7.0
```

The [sys.path init documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html#sys-path-init) suggests being wary of setting PYTHONPATH, so my final question:

**3) Is using PYTHONPATH this way appropriate or is there a better way?**